# html : haml as Java :?

Tags: java, haml

I'm a big fan of [haml](http://haml-lang.com/) in place of html/erb in Rails. Is there a similar tool for Java that makes the resulting code just as fast (still compiles to bytecode, after all), but which is less verbose to type/read/edit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/ is the closest to what you're looking for. No significant whitespace to force indentation (as I gather you want from your Hacker News thread), but that's a very controversial feature and Eclipse of all groups is not going to be the one to bring that to Java.

Comment: I actually like indentation as meaning, personally, and I like what I'm seeing so far with Xtend. I would take it one step further and eliminate the braces, replacing them with indentation - but this is good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Mirah](http://www.mirah.org/) or [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) if you *really* need native bytecode compilation. But for most applications, JRuby should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is [JHaml](https://github.com/raymyers/JHaml) that aims to do that, you should check the project and if it fits your needs (and if it doesn't, why not contribute to it?).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't mean that I wanted to use HAML in Java, I meant that I want a tool that makes writing Java shorter, yet clear, the way haml does that for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of Jade which I used while trying out NodeJs. Recently it seems there is a java implementation [jade4j](https://github.com/neuland/jade4j) and even a spring MVC integration project [spring-jade4j](https://github.com/neuland/spring-jade4j)